Does this weak omniscience principle have a name?
In constructive analysis, I'm looking at principles which follow both when there exists at least one discontinuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (equivalent to WLPO i.e. $x > 0$ or $x \leq 0$, holds for anything similar to classical real analysis) while also being true in real analysis when all functions are continuous (true for the internal logic of many real-world topoi including $\operatorname{Sh}(M)$ where $M$ is a manifold, or for the effective topos, or in the effective topos, and generally in both Brouwerian and Russian-style constructive mathematics).
One of these is this weakening of WLPO: for any function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , if $f(x) > 0$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x < 0$, then $f(x) > 0$. Clearly this follows from WLPO, but it also follows from $f$ being continuous so that each case can be extended to an open neighbourhood of the half segments.
This is a very convenient lemma to get rid of epsilons in upper bounds. Does it have a name? Is it provable in Bishop's axiomatization or in arbitrary spatial toposes?

Quick observation: the weakened WLPO in the question also follows from Markovs Principle. Since for every f, we have that not f(x) implies not x > 0 and not not x > 0, so we have not not f(x) > 0 and by MP f(x) > 0

Another note: the version of this theorem with non-strict inequalities is straightforward to prove in BISH. The hard part is getting the version with strict inequalities to work.
